# Which electronic device is this one below?

Tags: analog, components, identification

[image: unknown electronic component]

I found this thing in a piece of a very old circuit board. The shaft turns, inserting the black rods inside the metal cylinders. Inside each of the shiny cylinders there is a coil. It has 6 black rods in total. I have no idea what use this is intended for.

Comment: I've seen the name "permeability tuner" in this context, might be a useful search term

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very old automobile radios used one of these for tuning in the desired AM radio station.

I would see these when I was either disassembling or repairing these radio sets when I was a teenager. FWIW - that was a LONG time ago.

Comment: So they used one of these instead of a variable capacitor?

Comment: Inductors are resistant to vibration and dirt, so they work better in the automotive environment.  Could have one section for antenna tuning, one for AM LO, and maybe a third section for FM LO.

Comment: How old do you think this thing is?

Comment: You might want to add a few words to your answer to tell us what you think it is ... ;)

Answer (score 5):

That's a ganged variable inductor.

Comment: What is it used for?

Comment: Probably a tunable filter of some sort.  It would be interesting to know what sort of equipment it came out of.

Comment: The guy who gave me the circuit board with this thing said it was from a old radio I think.

Comment: Radio tuner would make a lot of sense.  Not sure why they didn't use a variable capacitor, though.  Those are a lot more common.  Might have something to do with operating at lower frequencies.